# Equations of motion for an object with non-constant acceleration related to its velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, velocity, integration

If I have an object flying through space with an initial velocity $v_0$ and undergoing constant acceleration $a$, then I can easily compute its velocity or displacement at any point in time $t$ using one of the classic equations of motion:

$$v(t) = v_0 + a t$$
$$x(t) = v_0 t + \frac 1 2 at^2$$

But what if the acceleration is *not* constant and depends on the velocity of the object itself at any given moment in time? Specifically, what if the acceleration at any given point in time is given by:

$$a(t) = C + Kv(t)$$

(Where $C$ and $K$ are both constants, and $0 \le K \le 1$.)

How can I compute $v(t)$ and $x(t)$ where acceleration is non-constant as defined above? (I understand how to derive the equations of motion using calculus when acceleration is constant or non-constant based on time, but I don't understand how to do it when a(t) is itself based on v(t), i.e. the very equation I'm trying to derive. It seems like a "chicken or egg" problem. Though I suspect once I have $v(t)$ I can simply integrate to get $x(t)$.

Comment: Start by using $a=dv/dt$. Next solve the differential equation for $v(t)$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deriving equations of motion using integration](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57953/)

Comment: And the derivation for terminal velocity is a great way to see this in action

Comment: @sammygerbil I think that answer would put me on the right path if my calculus fundamentals were better, but it's been 15 years since I touched calculus, so I'm kind of scratching my head. I understand how to derive the equations of motion using calculus when acceleration is constant, but I don't understand how to do it when $a(t)$ is itself based on $v(t)$, i.e. the very equation I'm trying to derive. It seems like a "chicken or egg" problem.

Comment: @WaltD The problem you are trying to solve requires calculus (integration, differential equations). There is no alternative. If your calculus skills are rusty you need to go back to your calculus textbook to re-learn those skills.

Comment: @sammygerbil I'm confused, where did I imply that I was looking for a non-calculus solution? I was only meaning to explain why the answer you linked didn't quite get me to a solution to my own problem and that I could use a bit more help being walked through the process, as Sam has so kindly done below. "Re-learn calculus" is honestly a very unhelpful and patronizing response.

Comment: @WaltD Your comment suggests that the reason you cannot deal with acceleration depending on velocity is because your knowledge of calculus is rusty. Recommending that you revise calculus ought to be helpful in such a case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All equations of motion can be solved using calculus. So the basics are as follows where $x$ is position, $v$ is velocity and $a$ is acceleration.
$$v=\frac {dx}{dt}$$
$$a=\frac {dv}{dt}=\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}=v\frac {dv}{dx}$$
Observe-
$$a(t) = C + Kv(t)$$
$$\frac{d\,v(t)}{dt} = C + Kv(t)$$
$$\frac{d\,v(t)}{C + Kv(t)} = dt$$
$$\int_0^t\frac{d\,v(t)}{C + Kv(t)} = \int_0^tdt$$
$$\biggl[\frac 1K \log(Kv(t)+C)\biggl]_0^t=\bigl[t\bigl]_0^t$$
$$\biggl[\frac 1K \log(Kv(t)+C)-\frac 1K \log(Kv(0)+C)\biggl]=\bigl[t-0\bigl]$$
$$\frac 1K \log\frac{Kv(t)+C}{Kv(0)+C}=t$$
$$Kv(t)+C=(Kv(0)+C)e^{Kt}$$
$$v(t)=\frac 1K (Kv(0)+C)e^{Kt}-C$$